# Disable the login screen on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, login-screen

Is it possible to disable the graphical login screen on CentOS 6, so that:

- It directly logs in with my user of choice
- It doesn't show the login screen after a period of inactivity

I do understand the potential security implications, this is just a virtual machine in my Windows machine.

Comment: This depends on the GUI you are using.  What desktop environment is it?

Comment: I'm using the default GUI: Gnome!